# How do I 'load' a storyboard with a specific id to an UIViewController?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Below is my code:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [UIViewController new];
if (indexPath.section == 0){
        UIViewController *controller;
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                controller = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileSettings"];
                [[viewController view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

All I want is to 'load' controller into viewController but I am not sure if it's possible.. can any of you explain what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would need to first create a new view controller, then instantiate another view controller and place it inside the view controller you initially created.

It would be better to do something like this:

```
id viewController;
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            viewController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifer:@"ProfileSettings"];
    // etc etc

// Display view controller as required
```

...however, if what you're actually trying to do is place your instantiated storyboard view controller **inside** of another view controller then you'll have to use view controller containment, which is available from iOS 5 onwards. View controller containment works like this:

```
[vc addChildViewController:instantiatedController];
[vc.view addSubview:instantiatedController.view];
```

But I'm not sure whether you really need to do that. It looks from the code you posted like there's no real need to use containment.